TypeScript constructors which return an object implicitly substitute the value of `this` for any callers of `super(...)`?
I'm trying to understand a line in the handbook:

In ES2015, constructors which return an object implicitly substitute the value of this for any callers of super(...). It is necessary for generated constructor code to capture any potential return value of super(...) and replace it with this.

The entire line is vague for me. Can someone explain what happened here?

Look at this example. In the top "normal" case, inside the Bar constructor, the value of this doesn't change at all, so that new Bar() instanceof Bar will be true. But in the second "abnormal" case, the Foo superclass returns an object. And then somehow, magically, inside Bar, the this becomes the value returned from the superclass constructor, just by calling super(), so that new Bar() instanceof Bar will be false.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz: Yes, it solves my confusion.

The super "function call" is weird. For normal classes that don't return objects, this is just the current instance of the class being constructed.  The call to super() just operates on the same this, and so the final constructed object is an instance of the subclass:
class Foo {
    a = 10;
    constructor() { }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    z: number;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.z = 1;
    }
}

const b = new Bar();
console.log(b); // Bar: {a: 10, z: 1}
console.log(b instanceof Bar); // true

But if the superclass returns a value from its constructor, then somehow this in the subclass becomes that value. That allows subsequent references to this to refer to the same object that the superclass returns. So the subclass behaves "normally" except that the constructed object isn't actually an instance of the class:
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        return { a: 10 };
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    z: number;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.z = 1;
    }
}

const b = new Bar();
console.log(b); // {a: 10, z: 1}
console.log(b instanceof Bar); // false

That means the call to super() has to look like "call the superclass constructor like a function, sort of, and see if it returns anything". If so, then assign the result of that function to this.  As if you could write
this = superCtor.call(this) || this;

But you can't do that! You can't assign to this.  But it happens anyway, implicitly.  If you look at what happens when super constructors are called when downleveling code to a version of JS before class existed, you'll see something similar:
function Bar() {
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
    _this.z = 1;
    return _this;
}

And you see that the actual this has been replaced with a new _this variable everywhere.
Playground link to code
